# How to Mask internal links of a masked Domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-masking, domain-masking

I bought a premium Domain from godaddy and used it with a free webhost account (with wordpress installation) with domain masking.
i masked main domain but when i open some link (say about us page) in new tab it shows the url of free webhost(original Domain)
eg. original freehost url: example.byethost.com
masked it with www.example.org
when i open(say "about us" page) in new tab than url in new tab shows example.byethost.com/aboutus which is not desired url i want it as www.example.org/aboutus

kindly help
thank you
Ps: I am a newbie

Comment: No sir i am not using frames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your WordPress installation's general settings.

[image: WordPress General Settings]

Change your `WordPress` and `Site Address (URL)` to `http://www.example.org`. This will fix the links generated on all the blog pages to use your masked domain instead of the free webhost one.